# Kafka connect plugins

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

As you can see on my docker-compose.yaml file below I have configured a kafka-connect debezium.As you can seethe fields? : CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR and CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH are empty.We will therefore have to have an empty field at the connector-plugins level. That is: `curl -s localhost:8083/connector-plugins | jq .` should give an empty result.But when we do it we get this:

```
docker-compose-demo git:(main) ✗ curl -s localhost:8083/connector-plugins | jq.[{"class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector","type": "source","version": "3.6.1"},{"class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector","type": "source","version": "3.6.1"},{"class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector","type": "source","version": "3.6.1"}]
```

I did a cat of the connect-distributed.properties file and we see that the plugin-path is empty.

```
➜ docker-compose-demo git:(main) ✗ docker exec -ti kconnect cat /kafka/config/connect-distributed.properties | grep plugin.path
plugin.path=/home
```

Furthermore with the command `docker-compose-demo git:(main) ✗ docker exec -ti kconnect ls /home` we see that the `/home` is empty. We should not have any plugins.

Where do these plugins come from and how to remove them?

**You 'll see below the docker-compose.yaml.**

```
version: '2'
services:
#1-Un cluster kafka avec debezium/kafka:2.4.1.Final, on a 3 brokers kafka
    kafka-1:
        image: debezium/kafka:2.4
        container_name: kafka-1
        ports:
            - 9092:9092
        environment:
            - CLUSTER_ID=FFFFFF
            - BROKER_ID=1
            - KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@kafka-1:9092,2@kafka-2:9093,3@kafka-3:9094
            - KAFKA_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:39092,CONTROLLER://kafka-1:9092
            - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka-1:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:39092
            - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
            - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
    kafka-2:
        image: debezium/kafka:2.4
        container_name: kafka-2
        ports:
            - 9093:9093
        environment:
            - CLUSTER_ID=FFFFFF
            - BROKER_ID=2
            - KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@kafka-1:9092,2@kafka-2:9093,3@kafka-3:9094
            - KAFKA_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://:29093,EXTERNAL://:39093,CONTROLLER://kafka-2:9093
            - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka-2:29093,EXTERNAL://localhost:39093
            - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
            - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
    kafka-3:
        image: debezium/kafka:2.4
        container_name: kafka-3
        ports:
            - 9094:9094
        environment:
            - CLUSTER_ID=FFFFFF
            - BROKER_ID=3
            - KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@kafka-1:9092,2@kafka-2:9093,3@kafka-3:9094
            - KAFKA_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://:29094,EXTERNAL://:39094,CONTROLLER://kafka-3:9094
            - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka-3:29094,EXTERNAL://localhost:39094
            - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
            - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
    kconnect:
        image: debezium/connect:2.5
        container_name: kconnect
        ports:
            - 8083:8083
        environment:
            CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_configs
            OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_offsets
            STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: my_connect_statuses
            BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka-1:29092,kafka-2:29093,kafka-3:29094
            CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR: 
            CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH:

        depends_on:
            - kafka-1
            - kafka-2
            - kafka-3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should give an empty result

This is incorrect. Kafka comes with MirrorMaker2, which is based on Connect framework.

> Where do these plugins come from

There seems to be a misunderstanding that the JVM `CLASSPATH` is scanned **before** `plugin.path` setting. It's not a required setting.

> how to remove them?

You'd have to build your own Docker images with the `connect-mirror*.jar` files removed. There is no harm having the JAR files, or plugins there if you don't actually run MirrorMaker2 processes.